# Why is it so hard to make a simple bar plot in R? How can I easily turn a data frame into a barplot?

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart

I have a dataframe as such:

```
Categories        time a        time b      
Category 1        xxx.xx        xxx.xx
Category 2        xxx.xx        xxx.xx
.                 .             .
.                 .             .
.                 .             .
Category n        xxx.xx        xxx.xx
```

All I want is to create a simple grouped bar plot of time a vs time b by category. It shouldn't take more than a line of code and 5 minutes of my time. How can I do this simply? All the solutions I see involve doing a whole bunch of moving crap around before I can graph it.

Comment: Can you share reproducible sample data? It's hard to demonstrate code when all the values are `xxx.xx`. Are your times numbers, or timestamps, or dates, or something else?

Comment: And I'm confused about the barplot you want. Categories goes on the x-axis, I assume? And maybe the height of the bars is time, with colors to differentiate the a bars and the b bars? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimalist solution you want actually exists in base R.

Consider this data.

```
> head(dat, 3)
  Categories time.a time.b.
1  Category1  98.59   90.05
2  Category2 133.10  150.26
3  Category3  22.04   75.15
```

Plot:

```
barplot(t(dat[-1]), beside=TRUE, ylab="time")
```

***Yields***

[image]

You then can refine it as you wish, e.g.

```
rownames(dat) <- 1:10
barplot(t(dat[-1]), beside=TRUE, xlab="Categories", ylab="time", col=2:3)
legend("topleft", c("time a", "time b"), col=2:3, pch=15)
```

***which yields***

[image]

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(Categories = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 2L), .Label = c("Category1", "Category10", "Category2", 
"Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6", "Category7", 
"Category8", "Category9"), class = "factor"), time.a = c(98.59, 
133.1, 22.04, 10.24, 17.12, 78.21, 115.41, 76.84, 176.09, 73.02
), time.b. = c(90.05, 150.26, 75.15, 7.07, 1.85, 49.03, 7.41, 
152.89, 139.64, 90.98)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks! this is pretty much what I was looking for. By now I've given in and reformatted my data for ggplot2 (which is actually quite aesthetically pleasing, so I don't mind too much) but a lightweight solution is always handy!

Comment: In fact, I started with ggplot2. However, I caught myself switching off one feature after the other with a lot of extra code (e.g. grid lines, background stuff, candy colors) and noticed then that base plots rather gave me what I want. But decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

R is a robust language and it can produce very rich visualizations. All this power means the user has to have more levers to pull to produce the visualization they want, which steepens the learning curve. This is compounded by the fact that the most popular R visualization library (ggplot) is designed in a way that can seem strange to people coming from more object oriented languages or from spreadsheet programs.

I produced something like what I think you want.

```
df <- data.frame(cat=c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5", "cat6", "cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5", "cat6"),
             time_type=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"),
             time=c(12.7, 16, 8.6, 13.4, 7.3, 5.5, 6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))


head(df) 
        cat   time_type   time
    1   cat1  a           12.7
    2   cat2  a           16.0
    3   cat3  a           8.6   
    4   cat4  a           13.4  
    5   cat5  a           7.3   
    6   cat6  a           5.5   
    7   cat1  b           6.8
    8   cat2  b           15
    9   cat3  b           33
   10   cat4  b           4.2
   11   cat5  b           10
   12   cat6  b           29.5
```

and to produce the graph

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=cat, y=time, fill=time_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image: barplot_in_r]

edit:

And you can produce this dataframe from your original dataframe like this

```
df2 <- data.frame(cat=c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5", "cat6"),
                 time_a=c(12.7, 16, 8.6, 13.4, 7.3, 5.5),
                 time_b=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
head(df2)

    cat     time_a  time_b
1   cat1    12.7    6.8 
2   cat2    16.0    15.0    
3   cat3    8.6     33.0    
4   cat4    13.4    4.2 
5   cat5    7.3     10.0    
6   cat6    5.5     29.5
```

And from there, you can simply melt your dataframe like so:

```
library(reshape2)
df3 <- melt(df2)
df3


cat     variable  value
cat1    time_a    12.7      
cat2    time_a    16.0      
cat3    time_a    8.6       
cat4    time_a    13.4      
cat5    time_a    7.3       
cat6    time_a    5.5       
cat1    time_b    6.8       
cat2    time_b    15.0      
cat3    time_b    33.0      
cat4    time_b    4.2   
cat5    time_b    10.0      
cat6    time_b    29.5  

ggplot(data=df3, aes(x=cat, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: This is my best guess as to what OP wants as well, but it would be a much better answer if you showed them how to get from the data format in the question to the format you use in the answer.

Comment: Well, actually I took the time just now to familiarize myself with ggplot2 and it's really quite nice actually, so I guess I can deal with the hassle of reformatting my data. What I wanted before, primarily, was to avoid having to reformat my data from my original data.frame in any way.

Comment: I've edited my response to show how to easily reformat your data into the structure I used in my barplot.